# Heap or Stack? When a constant string is referred in function call in C++

Tags: c++, function, global-variables, heap-memory, stack-memory

Consider the function:

```
char *func()
{
    return "Some thing";
}
```

Is the constant `string` (`char` array) `"Some thing"` stored in the stack as local to the function call or as global in the heap?

I'm *guessing* it's in the heap.

If the function is called multiple times, how many copies of `"Some thing"` are in the memory? (And is it the heap or stack?)

Comment: I'm tempted to add another answer just to add to the confusion.

Comment: Note the function is returning the wrong type. It should be `char const*`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String literal "Some thing" is of type `const char*`. So, they are neither on heap nor on stack but on a read only location which is a implementation detail.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)

> Data
>
> The data area contains global and static variables used by the program
>   that are initialized. This segment can be further classified into
>   initialized read-only area and initialized read-write area. For
>   instance the string defined by char s[] = "hello world" in C and a C
>   statement like int debug=1 outside the "main" would be stored in
>   initialized read-write area. And a C statement like const char* string
>   = "hello world" makes the string literal "hello world" to be stored in
>   initialized read-only area and the character pointer variable string
>   in initialized read-write area. Ex: static int i = 10 will be stored
>   in data segment and global int i = 10 will be stored in data segment

Comment: +1, This is more correct, because where the string literal resides is indeed an Implementation Detail.

Comment: Worth adding to this that on systems there is such read-only memory, writing to such a string will cause a crash. Were the string itself on the heap, stack or read/write data segment, you'd likely get away with it. This illustrates why understanding which data is in static segments is important.

Comment: It is incorrect >> `String literal "Some thing" is of type const char*.`  The type of the string literal is `const char[11]`.

Comment: @Nawaz - Aren't string literals of type const char*? Could you please add any citance to it.

Comment: @Mahesh: No Mahesh. If they were of type `cont char*`, then this program would given compilation error : http://www.ideone.com/oG0Pe ... because `const char*` cannot convert into `const char[N]`.

Comment: @Mahesh: C++03, §2.13.4/1 says :  *A string literal that does not begin with L is an ordinary string literal, also referred to as a narrow string literal. An ordinary string literal has type **“array of n
const char”** and static storage duration (3.7), where n is the size of the string as defined below, and is initialized with the given characters.*

Answer (score 2):

Constant strings are usually placed with program code, which is neither heap nor stack (this is an implementation detail).  Only one copy will exist, each time the function returns it will return the same pointer value (this is guaranteed by the standard).  Since the string is in program memory, it is possible that it will *never* be loaded into memory, and if you run two copies of the program then they will share the same copy in RAM (this only works for read-only strings, which includes string constants in C).

Comment: And on ELF systems, such string literals are usually in the `.rodata` (read-only data) section.

Comment: Confusing sentence: "Since the string is in program memory, it is possible that it will never be loaded into memory". What do you mean?

Comment: I was confused too. But I guess the 1st memory means .text or .data (static/read only part), the 2nd memory means heap and stack

Answer (score 1):

Neither, its in the static section of the program. Similar to having the string as a global variable. There is only ever one copy of the string within the translation unit.

Comment: Common, but not guaranteed. It is possible that `"X" != "X"`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither on the heap, nor on stack, it is part of the so-called [init section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) in the executable image (COFF). This is loaded into memory and contains stuff like strings.