# What are the differences and similarities between global variables and heap variables in c?

Tags: c, global-variables, heap-memory

What are the differences and similarities between global variables and heap variables in c?

Suppose I have this piece of code.

```
const char* globalVar = "This is a string";

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* heapVar = malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
}
```

So what are the differences and similarities between globalVar and heapVar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it const char*, for safety, since you can't write on that string.

Comment: Note: your `heapVar` is actually an automatic ("stack") variable which **points to** heap storage. Once main() returns or exits, 'heapVar` does not exist anymore, but *the object that it referred to* is still in existance. For main() this is of course a minor point, (if main returns, the program is not supposed to exist anymore, except for atexit handlers), but for "ordinary" functions the distinction is very clear. And the result a memory leak.

Comment: +1 Notice that wildpasser said: heapVar points to heap storage, but it's in the stack.

Comment: We are answering a very basic homework question that OP’s professor would like OP to be able to figure out by paying attention to his/her notes/textbook/course materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables and heap variables are two different concepts.  A heap variable simply tells you where space for the variable was allocated, while a global variable tells you the scope of the variable.

Global means the variable is visible to anything, and it is opposed to local which means a variable's visibility is restricted.

Heap means the variable (pointer) was dynamically allocated (eg: with malloc), and is opposed to stack where the variable was not dynamically allocated.

So you can have a global heap variable, a global stack variable, a local heap variable or a local stack variable.

In your case, globalVar is global because it is declared outside of the scope (braces) of any function, while heapVar is local to main.  heapVar is declared on the heap because of the call to malloc.  globalVar is a special case because it's using a char* declaration.

For more details on how char* style declarations are handled, please see:
[Heap or Stack? When a constant string is referred in function call in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440185/heap-or-stack-when-a-constant-string-is-refered-in-function-call-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The global variable is always there, it never disappear. More, it is visible in all the functions in that file/module and, unless declared as "static", it is also visible across the file/module.

Beware that your global variable is not "This is a string", but only that globalVariable, which is just a pointer (that contains an address in memory).

The heapVar variable contains an address towards something on the heap. That variable is only visible inside the main() function.

You *can* make global variables to point towards the heap.

The difference here is that the content pointed by globalVariable is statically allocated, while the content pointed by heapVar is dynamically allocated (you can destroy it by calling free() and free memory, while you cannot free memory used by that string "This is a string", which is the content pointed by globalVar).

Answer (score 0):

**NB**: Here I talk about globarVar and heapVar, not about the memory that they're pointing.
The difference are:

**The scope**

**heapVar is in the stack, not in the heap**, so it's scope is local to it's function, and globarVar is assessible anywhere.

**The life**

heapVar dies when the function call ends, globarVar lifes for all the duration of the program.

**About the memory they're pointing:**

The memory pointed by heapVar is in the heap, while the memory pointed by globarVar is in an implementation defined readonly memory, make it be const char* for safety:

```
char* globalVar = "This is a string";
```

The memory in the heap can be freed at any time, the literal string lives for all the duration of the program.
In your case you're having a leak.Anyway I understand that this is only an example, maybe you're aware of it.