# Where is the memory for this allocated?

Tags: c

```
#define NAME "stackoverflow"
void a()
{
    char *name = NAME;
}
```

My assumption would be stack. The assignment looked slightly odd to me. Is this a good thing to do?

Comment: The type of `name` should be `const char*` as string literals are not modifiable.

Comment: Neither the stack nor the heap, see [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440185/heap-or-stack-when-a-constant-string-is-refered-in-function-call-in-c

Comment: If you think about it, as the stack is a LIFO structure, where would it go on there? Constants are just that, not context sensitive WRT the execution path of the process, so I think it'd be very difficult (i.e. almost impossible) to create stack level constants.

Comment: I think @JeffWatkins nailed it better as duplicate. We should reference that instead.

Comment: Thanks for finding the dup guys. Im assuming its very much a valid thing to do as far I declare the pointer as a const char *.