# Why do I get cannot convert from const char[5] to char* in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
char* f() {
   cout << b;
   return "B::f";
}
```

Ok so I have this piece of code inside a class and I keep get this error

```
'return': cannot convert from 'const char [5]' to 'char*'
```

I tried some online compilers and it works just fine .

So why is this happening ?

Comment: "B::f" is of type `const char *` - obviously not the same type your function returns (`char *`). Also, why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: Thanks for answering ! Im a student in informatics and Im not very well accustomed to correctly using the std , I just used using namespace std; at the begining of the code. Also the f() is a virtual function "virtual char* f() = 0;" and changing it to const char * would trow me an error . I was just wondering why this is only happening in VS . In any other compiler I tried it works just fine. The task requires me to use the virtual function as it is given.

Comment: Enable all warnings and you'll see all compilers complaining about that. and [`using namespace std` is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7440203/6414842 for a better explanation on why this happens.

Comment: You mangled the error message pretty badly.  Fixed to match the snippet, verify that the edit is good.  And no, C++ forbids converting a string literal (aka const char[]) to char[] or char*, that is a const violation.  C does allow it for histerical reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of this function indicates that the storage it points to can be changed. However you return a literal, which does not allow modifications.

Change the signature to

```
const char* f();
```

and it will work.